# How to ser Highchart Grid Color pattern

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts polar-spider chart. Is there any way to set color pattern in grid.
There is yAxis.alternateGridColor but i need pattern in color.

[Poler chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider)

Please check below image so you can get idea, What i am talking about.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs7cI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plot-bands to achieve the required result:

```
    yAxis: {
        ...,
        plotBands: [{
            color: 'red',
            from: 20,
            to: 50
        }, ...]
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g62h0apb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotBands